# Chef Knife Bootstrap Vagrant VM - Connection errors

Tags: chef-infra, virtualbox, bootstrapping, knife

My environment: Virtualbox, CentOs VM 6.5 with chef client installed
Ubuntu 12.04 Vagrant Box

Issue: I am trying to `$knife boostrap vagrant.vm -x vagrant -N "target1"`, but I am getting to different error messages:

```
"Connecting to vagrant.vm"
ERROR: Network Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known. Check your knife configuration and network settings.
```

I tried connecting to the Vagrant VM using the IP 127.0.0.1

```
Error: Network error: connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1 port 22. Check your knife configuration and network settings.
```

I can ssh as vagrant@127.0.0.1 into the vagrant box with no issues.
The `/etc/hostname` has the correct IP and FQDN of VM.

Why is the knife boot strap command failing to connect to my Vagrant VM? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you connect using `ssh vagrant@vagrant.vm` from your machine?

Comment: No.  /etc/hostname 127.0.0.1 localhost 127.0.1.1 vagrant.vm vagrant allowed me to ssh using the IP of 127.0.0.1. I removed everything except 127.0.0.1 and vagrant.vm. I did a hostname -F /etc/hostname. This prevented me from sshing into the vagrant box. I added the the hostnames and IPs back, reran hostname -F /etc/hostname, and still can't ssh into the box.

Comment: I restored my snapshot in CentOS. I can ssh into the vagrant VM from my mac. I can't ssh from CentOS VM to Vagrant VM. $ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222. Connect  to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222 connection refused. I started ssh again. $netstat -pnl | grep. SSH is listening. I removed the -p flag and ran the command $ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1.  I connect to the Vagrant VM now, but it will not accept my password of "vagrant." Permission denied, please try again. I need to connect to the Vagrant VM from CentOS because CentOS VM has Chef workstation installed to run the knife bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

When vagrant starts a machine, it does not listen on port 22 directly on localhost; the machine will listen on port 22, but Vagrant sets up port forwarding for SSH, and the exact specifics are up to the provider (virtualbox vs vmware, etc), and the networking options (bridged, host only, etc), which can be set in the [Vagrantfile](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/).

After you `vagrant up`, you'll see output that looks like this:

```
default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2201.
default: Starting the VMware VM...
default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 192.168.21.131:22
...
default: Forwarding ports...
default: -- 22 => 2201
```

So after the machine is up, we can SSH directly:

```
% ssh -p2201 vagrant@localhost
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:2201' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
vagrant@localhost's password:
Last login: Mon Apr 20 04:18:44 2015 from 192.168.21.1
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

Then `knife bootstrap` can be done using the port option, `-p 2201`.

However, I wonder why you're using `knife bootstrap` against a vagrant machine. Vagrant supports using Chef directly as a provisioner, using chef-solo, chef-client with a regular Chef Server, chef-zero (an in-memory Chef Server often used for testing), or chef-apply. See the provisioning documentation on the vagrant site for specifics.

- http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html

Comment: I am learning Chef through Opscode's Nathan Harvey. I'm on tutorial module 3 https://vimeo.com/78852767. Minute 8:50 is where he says to use knife to bootstrap. Thanks for the documentation link. I have not used Vagrant with chef as a provisioner before, but I will look into this as I get more experience.